# What css style can I use to change location of my radio buttons

Tags: css

[image]

How can I lower the radio buttons to be same height as Male and Female? I tried width or height both did not work I even tried padding and it didn't work.

Comment: Please add your html/css code.

Comment: use "vertical-align: top" and then use margin. It will work.

Comment: I usually use position:relative; + top:3px;

Comment: Use vertical align property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Try this:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-top: -1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Your parent div by the way need to has height set.**

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example works for me out of the box:

```html
<form>
  <span>Gender</span>
    <fieldset style="display:inline; border:0;">
    <label><input type="radio"/> Female</label>
    <label><input type="radio"/> Male</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css :

```css
    .maxl{
      margin:25px ;
    }
    .inline{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .inline + .inline{
      margin-left:10px;
    }
    .radio{
      color:#999;
      font-size:15px;
      position:relative;
    }
    .radio span{
      position:relative;
       padding-left:20px;
    }
    .radio span:after{
      content:'';
      width:15px;
      height:15px;
      border:3px solid;
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:1px;
      border-radius:100%;
      -ms-border-radius:100%;
      -moz-border-radius:100%;
      -webkit-border-radius:100%;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"]{
       cursor: pointer; 
      position:absolute;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"]:checked + span{
      color:#0B8;  
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"]:checked + span:before{
        content:'';
      width:5px;
      height:5px;
      position:absolute;
      background:#0B8;
      left:5px;
      top:6px;
      border-radius:100%;
      -ms-border-radius:100%;
      -moz-border-radius:100%;
      -webkit-border-radius:100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="maxl">
  <label class="radio inline"> 
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>
      <span> Male </span> 
   </label>
  <label class="radio inline"> 
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
      <span>Female </span> 
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice formatting but that is IMHO total out of scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input{
  
  vertical-align:bottom;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <span>Gender</span>
    <label><input type="radio" name="select_gender"/> Male</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="select_gender"/> Female</label>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.